# URL masking with .htaccess. Need to simply mask not redirect

Tags: .htaccess

Hi everyone I'm new here. Thank you for having me. Hopefully this is a very simple question. I have a subdomain pointing to my server. I'm trying to mask my URL using the htaccess file, but it's redirecting me instead. Is there any way to mask only?

My primary domain `www.example.com`is pointing to my HostGator server with my website.

I made a subdomain `portal.example.com` which I'm using a redirect to point it to my local IIS server I host at my business. When someone uses the portal link the address bar shows my server IP address. I was trying to figure out a way to mask the IP and have it say `portal.example.com`.

HostGator explained I could achieve this using the htaccess and following the instructions https://www.exabytes.my/blog/domain-masking/

Is this even a possibility?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand... It sounds like you're talking about a DNS issue not a `.htaccess` one. If you want the users to see a specific website name then you have to buy it and set the appropriate records (i.e. `A`) to point at your `IP`

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask. Your rule is an explicit redirection, if you do not want that then don't, take out the `R=301` which _explicitly_ redirects. Next, if you do not want IP addresses visible in the URL bar (which makes sense), then don't redirect to an IP address, but a host name instead. Please take the time to edit your question. Revise it. Explain what you actually mean by "mask a URL" (that is no known expression) and what it actually is you are trying to achieve, not how you think you might be able to do that. Try to read the question with our eyes...

Comment: why did you remove your current rewriting rules from the question? How do you expect us to help now? Of course it is possible to use a host name in a URL, why shouldn't it? The question is: why is the IP address shown in your URL bar? Why do you redirect the client to the IP address? Redirect the client to the host name and all is fine...